# How to set fields are not required in mongoDb using Grails 2.2.2

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I create my first app in Grails 2.2.2 .. For database i am using MongoDb .. but it gives me an error if all fields are not filled..How to set mongoDb fields allows null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default GORM does not allow insert null value into database, but you can turn it off global by putting in Config.groovy: grails.gorm.default.constraints = { '*'(nullable: true) }

Answer (score 1):

Have tried to set property of fields null-able

> static constraints =  {    fieldName nullable: true }